# Copy multiple cells from workbook a to workbook b keeping keeping the exact reference to the cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am building a catalog I have all data and costing listed in workbook1.  Now I need to reference workbook2 the customer catalog, back to workbook1 so all data only needs to be updated in one place.  When in the function box you type = in workbook2 and pick a cell in workbook1 you get the $ around the cell location holding the exact cell. The data in workbook1 is in columns, I would like to drag the cell down in workbook2 and have it change the reference to workbook1 to the next row and still have the $ exact reference. Any suggestion for coping locations in blocks and pasting it keeping the exact reference to all cells with the $, Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don’t understand this.  What do you mean by “get the cells below the referenced cell and keep the $ exact reference in all cells”?  Can you give an example? … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a range reference to the other workbook in combination wit INDEX

```
INDEX('[WB]WS!'A1:A10,ROW(A1), 1)
```

The row reference makes it possible to drag the function down.
(the a1:a10 should be with dollarsigns, but I cannot find the sign on my phone ;-) )

Comment: my formula in workbookB is
='[PE Data Spec Book 2019.xlsx]Product List'!$P$8405  When I drag it down I get
='[PE Data Spec Book 2019.xlsx]Product List'!$P$8405
='[PE Data Spec Book 2019.xlsx]Product List'!$P$8405
='[PE Data Spec Book 2019.xlsx]Product List'!$P$8405
='[PE Data Spec Book 2019.xlsx]Product List'!$P$8405

when I drag it down in workbookb it stays at 8405 I need it to change to 8406 8407 and so on as I drag down.

Comment: Sorry I misread the question